# Forecast with ggplot2 and funggcast function

Tags: r, ggplot2, forecasting

On [this](http://davenportspatialanalytics.squarespace.com/blog/2012/3/14/plotting-forecast-objects-in-ggplot-part-1-extracting-the-da.html) website, Mr. Davenport published a function to plot an arima forecast with `ggplot2` on the example of an arbitrary dataset, he published [here](http://davenportspatialanalytics.squarespace.com/blog/2012/3/21/plotting-forecast-objects-in-ggplot-part-2-visualize-observa.html). I can follow his example without any error message.

Now, when I use my data, I would end with the warning:

```
1: In window.default(x, ...) : 'end' value not changed
2: In window.default(x, ...) : 'end' value not changed
```

I know that it happens when I call this command `pd <- funggcast(yt, yfor)` due to an issue with the data I indicate in my data `end = c(2013)`. But I do not know how to fix that.

This is the code I use:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)
library(forecast)

myts <- ts(rnorm(55), start = c(1960), end = c(2013), freq = 1)
funggcast <- function(dn, fcast){

en <- max(time(fcast$mean)) # Extract the max date used in the forecast

# Extract Source and Training Data
ds <- as.data.frame(window(dn, end = en))
names(ds) <- 'observed'
ds$date <- as.Date(time(window(dn, end = en)))

# Extract the Fitted Values (need to figure out how to grab confidence intervals)
dfit <- as.data.frame(fcast$fitted)
dfit$date <- as.Date(time(fcast$fitted))
names(dfit)[1] <- 'fitted'

ds <- merge(ds, dfit, all.x = T) # Merge fitted values with source and training data

# Extract the Forecast values and confidence intervals
dfcastn <- as.data.frame(fcast)
dfcastn$date <- as.Date(as.yearmon(row.names(dfcastn)))
names(dfcastn) <- c('forecast','lo80','hi80','lo95','hi95','date')

pd <- merge(ds, dfcastn,all.x = T) # final data.frame for use in ggplot
return(pd)

} 

yt <- window(myts, end = c(2013)) # extract training data until last year
yfit <- auto.arima(myts) # fit arima model
yfor <- forecast(yfit) # forecast
pd <- funggcast(yt, yfor) # extract the data for ggplot using function funggcast()

ggplot(data = pd, aes(x = date,y = observed)) + geom_line(color = "red") + geom_line(aes(y = fitted), color = "blue") + geom_line(aes(y = forecast)) + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lo95, ymax = hi95), alpha = .25) + scale_x_date(name = "Time in Decades") + scale_y_continuous(name = "GDP per capita (current US$)") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10), legend.justification=c(0,1), legend.position=c(0,1)) + ggtitle("Arima(0,1,1) Fit and Forecast of GDP per capita for Brazil (1960-2013)") + scale_color_manual(values = c("Blue", "Red"), breaks = c("Fitted", "Data", "Forecast"))
```

**Edit:** I found another blog [here](http://librestats.com/2012/06/11/autoplot-graphical-methods-with-ggplot2/) with a function to use with `forecast` and `ggplot2` but I would like to use the approach above, if I were able to find my mistake. Anyone?

**Edit2:**
If I run your updated code with my data [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/109495328/gdp_brazil.csv), than I get the graph down below. Note that I did not change the `end = c(2023)` for `mtys`, otherwise it would not merge the forecasted with the fitted value.

```
myts <- ts(WDI_gdp_capita$Brazil, start = c(1960), end = c(2023), freq = 1)

funggcast <- function(dn, fcast){

  en <- max(time(fcast$mean)) # Extract the max date used in the forecast

  # Extract Source and Training Data
  ds <- as.data.frame(window(dn, end = en))
  names(ds) <- 'observed'
  ds$date <- as.Date(time(window(dn, end = en)))

  # Extract the Fitted Values (need to figure out how to grab confidence intervals)
  dfit <- as.data.frame(fcast$fitted)
  dfit$date <- as.Date(time(fcast$fitted))
  names(dfit)[1] <- 'fitted'

  ds <- merge(ds, dfit, all = T) # Merge fitted values with source and training data

  # Extract the Forecast values and confidence intervals
  dfcastn <- as.data.frame(fcast)
  dfcastn$date <- as.Date(paste(row.names(dfcastn),"01","01",sep="-"))
  names(dfcastn) <- c('forecast','lo80','hi80','lo95','hi95','date')

  pd <- merge(ds, dfcastn,all.x = T) # final data.frame for use in ggplot
  return(pd)

} # ggplot function by Frank Davenport

yt <- window(myts, end = c(2013)) # extract training data until last year
yfit <- auto.arima(yt) # fit arima model
yfor <- forecast(yfit) # forecast
pd <- funggcast(myts, yfor) # extract the data for ggplot using function funggcast()

ggplot(data = pd, aes(x = date, y = observed)) + geom_line(color = "red") + geom_line(aes(y = fitted), color = "blue") + geom_line(aes(y = forecast)) + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lo95, ymax = hi95), alpha = .25) + scale_x_date(name = "Time in Decades") + scale_y_continuous(name = "GDP per capita (current US$)") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10), legend.justification=c(0,1), legend.position=c(0,1)) + ggtitle("Arima(0,1,1) Fit and Forecast of GDP per capita for Brazil (1960-2013)") + scale_color_manual(values = c("Blue", "Red"), breaks = c("Fitted", "Data", "Forecast")) + ggsave((filename = "gdp_forecast_ggplot.pdf"), width=330, height=180, units=c("mm"), dpi = 300, limitsize = TRUE)
```

The almost perfect graph I get:
[image]

**One additional question: How can I get a legend in this graph?**

If I set `end = c(2013)` for `myts`, I get the same graph as in the beginning:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several points that are different between Mr Davenport's analysis and the plot you are trying to make.
The first one is that he is comparing the the arima forecast to some observed data, which is why he trains the model on a portion of the whole time series, the training set. 
To do this, you should make your initial time series longer:

```
myts <- ts(rnorm(55), start = c(1960), end = c(2023), freq = 1)
```

Then at the end of your script, where you select the training up to 2013:

```
yt <- window(myts, end = c(2013)) # extract training data until last year
```

The model should be trained on the training set, not the whole time series, so you should change the yfit line to:

```
yfit <- auto.arima(yt) # fit arima model
```

And call the funggcast function using the whole time series, because it needs the observed and fitted data:

```
pd <- funggcast(myts, yfor)
```

Finally, he uses dates that have month and year, so in his `funggcast` function,  change this line:

```
dfcastn$date <- as.Date(as.yearmon(row.names(dfcastn)))
```

To:

```
dfcastn$date <- as.Date(paste(row.names(dfcastn),"01","01",sep="-"))
```

This is because the values predicted by the model need to be changed to dates, like 2014 has to be changed to 2014-01-01, in order to be merged with the observed data.

After all the changes, the code looks like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)
library(forecast)

myts <- ts(rnorm(55), start = c(1960), end = c(2013), freq = 1)
funggcast <- function(dn, fcast){

        en <- max(time(fcast$mean)) # Extract the max date used in the forecast

        # Extract Source and Training Data
        ds <- as.data.frame(window(dn, end = en))
        names(ds) <- 'observed'
        ds$date <- as.Date(time(window(dn, end = en)))

        # Extract the Fitted Values (need to figure out how to grab confidence intervals)
        dfit <- as.data.frame(fcast$fitted)
        dfit$date <- as.Date(time(fcast$fitted))
        names(dfit)[1] <- 'fitted'

        ds <- merge(ds, dfit, all.x = T) # Merge fitted values with source and training data

        # Extract the Forecast values and confidence intervals
        dfcastn <- as.data.frame(fcast)
        dfcastn$date <- as.Date(paste(row.names(dfcastn),"01","01",sep="-"))
        names(dfcastn) <- c('forecast','lo80','hi80','lo95','hi95','date')

        pd <- merge(ds, dfcastn,all= T) # final data.frame for use in ggplot
        return(pd)

} 

yt <- window(myts, end = c(2013)) # extract training data until last year
yfit <- auto.arima(yt) # fit arima model
yfor <- forecast(yfit) # forecast
pd <- funggcast(myts, yfor) # extract the data for ggplot using function funggcast()

plotData<-ggplot(data = pd, aes(x = date, y = observed)) + geom_line(aes(color = "1")) +
        geom_line(aes(y = fitted,color="2")) + 
        geom_line(aes(y = forecast,color="3")) +
        scale_colour_manual(values=c("red", "blue","black"),labels = c("Observed", "Fitted", "Forecasted"),name="Data")+
        geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lo95, ymax = hi95), alpha = .25)+
        scale_x_date(name = "Time in Decades") +
        scale_y_continuous(name = "GDP per capita (current US$)")+
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10)) + 
        ggtitle("Arima(0,1,1) Fit and Forecast of GDP per capita for Brazil (1960-2013)")

plotData
```

And you get a plot that looks like this, the fitting is pretty bad with a completely random time series. Also ggplot will output some errors because the forecast line has no data before 2013 and the fitted data does not go on after 2013. (I ran it several times, depending on the initial, random time series, the model might just predict 0 everywhere)

[image]

Edit: changed the `pd` assignment line as well, in case there are no observed data after 2013

Edit2: I changed the ggplot function at the end of the code to make sure the legend shows up

Comment: Thank you, NicE, for your reply! I have one follow-up question. My data is actually not random and consists of 54 observations (from 1960 to 2013), see ggtitle. Thus, I cannot extend `myts` deliberately. When I do that anyway than `myts` repeats the observation it contains from the beginning. How can I avoid this? By inserting `NA`!? Or in other words (if you look at your graph): how can I avoid that the red line is going beyond the grey area?

Comment: I edited the `pd` assignment line and the `myts` description to fit your case, you get the `warnings` that you posted because 2013 is the end of the training series and you are predicting until 2023 so `en` is 2023. NAs are automatically added for the observed and fitted values after 2013 in the final data frame

Comment: Thanks for the quick edit. Can you indicate the new `pd` assignment, I cannot find it in the code!?

Comment: sure, I changed the last line in the funggcast function  `pd <- merge(ds, dfcastn,all= T)`. Changed `all.x=T` to `all=T` to make sure all lines from both dataframes are kept. Otherwise during the merge, no lines from the forecasted data are kept because they are absent from the `ds` dataframe that holds the fitted and observed data up to 2013

Comment: I think we are almost there, but yet I cannot get the red line off the time period after 2014, see **Edit2**. I added a small question about how to add a legend to this graph since all my private attempts where to no avail. Thank you, NicE.

Comment: In the Edit2 you posted, replace `pd <- merge(ds, dfcastn,all.x = T)` by `pd <- merge(ds, dfcastn,all = T)` (see my previous comments for the reason), and you can leave the `myts <- ts(rnorm(55), start = c(1960), end = c(2013), freq = 1)` to `end=c(2013)` instead of `end=c(2023)`, this should make the correct plot

Comment: Edited the ggplot function to make the legend appear, see in my code in the initial post.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I see the mistake I did. It functions now to my full joy! Thank you very much, NicE!!

Answer (score 2):

There is a package called ggfortify available via github which allows straight plotting of forecast objects with ggplot2. It can be found on http://rpubs.com/sinhrks/plot_ts

Answer (score 1):

This is a bump on a rather old post, but there's a [fuction in github](https://gist.github.com/fernandotenorio/3889834) that produces some nice results.

Here's the code as it was on Aug 03, 2016:

```
function(forec.obj, data.color = 'blue', fit.color = 'red', forec.color = 'black',
                           lower.fill = 'darkgrey', upper.fill = 'grey', format.date = F)
{
    serie.orig = forec.obj$x
    serie.fit = forec.obj$fitted
    pi.strings = paste(forec.obj$level, '%', sep = '')

     if(format.date)
        dates = as.Date(time(serie.orig))
    else
        dates = time(serie.orig)

    serie.df = data.frame(date = dates, serie.orig = serie.orig, serie.fit = serie.fit)

    forec.M = cbind(forec.obj$mean, forec.obj$lower[, 1:2], forec.obj$upper[, 1:2])
    forec.df = as.data.frame(forec.M)
    colnames(forec.df) = c('forec.val', 'l0', 'l1', 'u0', 'u1')

    if(format.date)
        forec.df$date = as.Date(time(forec.obj$mean))
    else
        forec.df$date = time(forec.obj$mean)

    p = ggplot() + 
        geom_line(aes(date, serie.orig, colour = 'data'), data = serie.df) + 
        geom_line(aes(date, serie.fit, colour = 'fit'), data = serie.df) + 
        scale_y_continuous() +
        geom_ribbon(aes(x = date, ymin = l0, ymax = u0, fill = 'lower'), data = forec.df, alpha = I(0.4)) + 
        geom_ribbon(aes(x = date, ymin = l1, ymax = u1, fill = 'upper'), data = forec.df, alpha = I(0.3)) + 
        geom_line(aes(date, forec.val, colour = 'forecast'), data = forec.df) + 
        scale_color_manual('Series', values=c('data' = data.color, 'fit' = fit.color, 'forecast' = forec.color)) + 
        scale_fill_manual('P.I.', values=c('lower' = lower.fill, 'upper' = upper.fill))

    if (format.date)
        p = p + scale_x_date()

    p
}
```