# Time series forecasting in R - mention the range of prediction dates

Tags: r, time-series

I have used arima+stl model for time series forecast in R for predicting exchange rates.

```
ui.R
shinyUI(
sidebarLayout(   
headerPanel("Time Series forecasting with arima+stl"),
sidebarPanel(

  dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                 label = paste('Date range selection'),
                 start = textOutput("text1"),
                 end = textOutput("text2"), 
                 separator = " - ", 
                 weekstart = 1
  )
),
mainPanel(
  textOutput("text1"),
  textOutput("text2"),
  textOutput('forecast')   
) 
)
)
```

server.R

```
library(forecast)
parameters <- read.csv("~/RWD/stl+arima/data/parameters.csv")
shinyServer(
function(input, output, session){

      predictVariable <- ts(parameters[,2],start=c(2000,1),end=c(2009,12),frequency=12)
      fit.stl <- stl(predictVariable, s.window = "periodic")
      factors <- ts(as.data.frame(parameters[,3:8]),start=c(2000,1),end=c(2009,12),frequency=12)
      outfactors <- ts(parameters[,3:8],start=c(2010,1),end=c(2012,12),frequency = 12)
      output$forecast <- renderPrint({ forecast(fit.stl,h=10,
          forecastfunction=function(x,h,level=95){
              fit <- Arima(x,xreg=factors)
              return(forecast(fit,xreg=outfactors))})
   })
})
```

The above code is working fine. The data from 2000-2009 is used to forecast the exchange rates of next 3 years.My data is parameters.But I want to create a user interface where the user can mention the start and end dates for which he/she requires exchange rates forecast. In server.R, in the forecast function how do I use the dates taken as input in ui.R to mention the start and end dates for which I need the forecast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really broad question. I think you could have found many answers with some research. Here's one:

Try [Shiny](https://www.shinyapps.io/). Here is a [gallery](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/) of simple things you can do with it. There are great tutorials and posts on this site regarding Shiny.

Your function can be on the server.R script with a date range selection input on the ui.R script. You can customize your output to include specific forecasted values and even include a [graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244929/forecast-with-ggplot2-and-funggcast-function) of the forecast.

**Edit:** Including the recommended `funggcast` [function](http://www.r-bloggers.com/plotting-forecast-objects-in-ggplot-part-1-extracting-the-data/). Apply it to your forecast object to get a data frame containing your dates and forecasts. Your date input slider within your can refer to this table.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't explicitly mention the two R files before. I have edited my question now. How do I modify the forecast function in server.R to use the dates entered in ui.R?

Comment: I recommend using the `funggcast` function on your `forecast(fit)` object. `funggcast` is mentioned the 3rd link I included in my post. This will create a table out of your forecast object containing dates and forecasts. Your `dateRangeInput` can refer to this table.

Comment: I will incorporate that into my code. Thanks a lot:)

Comment: No problem! I edited my post to include the answer to your question. Please click the check if this solution solves your problem! Let me know if you run into any problems with this approach.